# C++11: using decltype on invalid expressions

Tags: c++11, decltype, enable-if

Say I have a struct (in real life, that's an automaton):

```
struct automaton
{
  bool get_final() const { return final; }
  void set_final()       { final = true; }
  bool final = false;
};
```

for which I want to provide a view that sees it transposed (iow, reversed, or mirrored).  Because I have more than just a single `automaton` class, I have a class template that wraps my automaton (I really want composition, not inheritance), and bounces all the function calls to the wrapped automaton, reversing what needs to be.  For sake of simplicity, here, it just forwards the calls.

By hand, I'd get

```
template <typename Aut>
struct transposed_by_hand
{
  Aut& aut;
  auto get_final() const -> bool
  {
    return aut.get_final();
  }

  auto set_final() -> void
  { 
    aut.set_final(); 
  }
};
```

But there are many functions, and I don't want to hard-code so much information (the function signature) in the wrapper.  Thanks to variadic templates and perfect forwarding for the incoming arguments, and `decltype` for the result, it's quite easy to have one macro to factor the definition of all the const member-functions, and another macro for non-const member functions (the difference being precisely the `const`).  Basically, in this case it boils down to this:

```
template <typename Aut>
struct transposed_with_decltype
{
  Aut& aut;
  auto get_final() const -> decltype(aut.get_final())
  {
    return aut.get_final();
  }

  auto set_final() -> decltype(aut.set_final())
  {
    aut.set_final(); 
  }
};
```

This works well for non-const automata, but breaks if I wrap a const automaton:

```
int main()
{
  const automaton aut;
  transposed_by_hand<const automaton> trh = { aut };
  transposed_with_decltype<const automaton> trd = { aut };
}
```

My compilers complain that (G++ 4.9):

```
f.cc: In instantiation of 'struct transposed_with_decltype<const automaton>':
f.cc:44:49:   required from here
f.cc:34:12: error: passing 'const automaton' as 'this' argument of 'void automaton::set_final()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       auto set_final() -> decltype(aut.set_final())
            ^
```

and (Clang++ 3.3):

```
f.cc:42:23: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const automaton' requires a user-provided default constructor
      const automaton aut;
                      ^
f.cc:34:36: error: member function 'set_final' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const automaton', but function is not marked const
      auto set_final() -> decltype(aut.set_final())
                                   ^~~
f.cc:44:49: note: in instantiation of template class 'transposed_with_decltype<const automaton>' requested here
      transposed_with_decltype<const automaton> trd = { aut };
                                                ^
f.cc:6:12: note: 'set_final' declared here
      void set_final()       { final = true; }
           ^
2 errors generated.
```

And they are right!  The expression in the `decltype` is breaking the const-ness of the wrapped automaton.  Yet, I am not going to use this function, I swear.  Just like I will not use the corresponding one wrapped by hand.

So my question is: is there a means to write the definition of the wrapping `set_final` so that I don't have to spell out its signature (input and output)?  I have tried to use `std::enable_if`, but it changes nothing to the problem here.  And anyway, it would need that the compiler be lazy, and accepts not to evaluate the second parameter of `std::enable_if` if it does not need to...

```
template <typename Aut>
struct transposed_with_decltype
{
  Aut& aut;
  auto get_final() const -> decltype(aut.get_final())
  {
    return aut.get_final();
  }

  auto set_final() -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<Aut>::value,
                                              decltype(aut.set_final())>::type
  {
    aut.set_final(); 
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that your member functions aren't templates, so their declaration is instantiated immediately, and the invalid expression causes a hard error. You can make your members templates through a dummy template parameter `template<class = void>` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it to work (using GCC 4.6) just by using the advice Xeo mentions in his comment.  That is, I turn the function into a trivial template, like so:

```
template<typename = void>
auto set_final() -> decltype(aut.set_final())  {
    return aut.set_final(); 
}
```

**== EDIT ==**

Luc Danton comments below that a more recent GCC may reject the code, complaining that the `decltype` isn't dependent.  I only have 4.6 here, but perhaps this could be worked around using something like this:

```
template<typename KLUDGE = int>
auto set_final() -> decltype((&aut+KLUDGE(0))->set_final())  {
    return aut.set_final(); 
}
```

YMMV.

Comment: With a recent enough GCC it will complain because `decltype(aut.set_final())` is not dependent.